# Access CentOS server Files From Windows GUI?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

I want to know if its possible to access linux filesystem / folder structure on a windows PC. As in be able to view / edit the server files in real time, from my windows PC. I've just set up a CentOS server locally, and am using putty to connect with it. The problem is I'll be using this server as a development server uploading a mass on php / html files to it which I need to test in real time.

My initial solution was to install git on the PC, but then I would have to push -> then pull "USING GITHUB" from my windows PC everytime I wanted to view a change. I think there is software that allows the server to listen for changes and then auto update the files but I wanted to see if this was an option first.

Comment: Push then pull? What?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Github is an online software you can use to push local code to github, you can then pull the code from github to a remote server. 

Find Out More Here: https://github.com

Comment: Sure, but you don't need to go anywhere near Github to use git.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Im not being funny but your comments aren't helping me in the slightest

Comment: You push from the Windows machine to the Linux machine. Major corporations across the world do that every (work)day.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've no idea how to push from machine to machine, i only know about pushing from local repos to ones hosted on github (I'm not in a major corp)

Comment: You just add a new [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) to the local repo and push there.

Comment: You can mount a linux drive as a network drive on your windows machine, typically using [samba](https://www.samba.org/).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I had no idea you could use git in this way, i use it on a very basic level. So i can put the remote address as an IP address?

Comment: Sure. You may also want to use `ssh` as the scheme instead of `http` or `https`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution its really helpful! Although id still have to git add / git commit / git push anytime i make changes right

Comment: @user4556274 Thanks ill take a look and let you know

Comment: Well, your solution is about using Windows Power Shell to connect to your Linux server with some add on to allow you to edit/save/change in time. take a look about windows power shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WinSCP which uses the secure copy protocol to transfer files between machines.  The program doesn't cost any money and uses port 22 (So as long as you can ssh to the machine it should work).  All you need is user credentials on the remote machine that have proper access to the directories you would like to work with.  Once logged in it presents you with the remote directory structure in a windows explorer like view.

Additionally the program has an option to **Keep remote directory up to date** which if set will:

> Once you start the function, WinSCP will register to receive notification whenever something changes in the selected local directory (and optionally in all its subdirectories). Once you make a change, for example when you save file in your favorite editor, WinSCP will receive notification about the change in the respective directory. Then it will perform synchronization of the local directory with the corresponding remote directory. Thus your change will be automatically reflected on the remote side.

Comment: This sounds great! Thank you so much for this, not knowing what is available to me makes coming up with solutions hard. Thanks again!

Comment: @YasminFrench so he deserve to accept his answer, kindly accept his answer :)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I was trying it out first and its EXACTLY what i wanted, thank you so much for this Jesse_b

Comment: @YasminFrench you welcome Yasso :P